# Serving high res images to retina display

Tags: javascript, css, retina-display

how to detect, **in a cross-browser compatible way**, the pixel density of the device visiting a webpage so that one can either serve standard or highres images without forcing doubled images to any device?

Is there any javascript library that automates this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Why setting for Retina

iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPad3, iPad4, Macbook 15", Macbook 13" all use Retina display.

Android also support high resolution display, as well as Windows 8(Lumia 920) as mentioned by @JamWaffles.

Adding high resolution support is good for user experience but it definitely add load for developer, as well as bandwidth for mobile. Somebody don't suggest doing that.(Peter-Paul Koch, see the bottom "further reading")

#### Breifing

There are two methods to implement this function. One is Javascript and the other is CSS. All current solutions are for Retina, but could extend to Android high resolution easily.

CSS solution is about Media Query and `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` or `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`

- Simple to use.
- Apply to all browsers.
- Disadvantage: Good for background. Harder for `<img>` tag

Javascript solution is about `window.devicePixelRatio` property.

- Advantage: Javascript could manipulate image source. So, if you are going to serve direct image instead of background, better to use Javascript
- Could not apply to all browsers but current support is good enough. See below for list.
- Need a bit more setting.

#### CSS Solution

For normal images, say an icon

```
.sample-icon {
    background-image: url("../images/sample-icon.png");
    background-size: 36px 36px;
}
```

For Retina, add those below

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), /* Webkit */
    (min-resolution: 192dpi) /* Everyone else */ {
    .sample-icon {
        background-image: url("../images/sample-icon-highres.png");
        background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

You can use `min-resolution: 2dppx` to replace `min-resolution: 192dpi`, for those who don't want to remember numbers

Note the difference:

1. Two different icons, one normal, one high res. High res icon is double size than normal one.
2. The background size. The later is half. But you need test it in your real use.

Resource:
+ http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/
+ http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/buttons/#CustomIcons

#### Javascript Solution

Use `window.devicePixelRatio` property to detect resolution.

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
  alert("This is a Retina screen");
  //Do something to manipulate image url attribute
  //for example add `@2x-` before all image urls
}
```

Browser Support

Safari, Android WebKit, Chrome 22+ and on Android, Opera Mobile, BlackBerry WebKit, QQ, Palm WebKit,
Ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html

#### For Android

Android device use 1.5 as high resolution instead of 2 in Retina.
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html  --#Targeting Device Density with CSS, #Targeting Device Density with JavaScript

#### Further Good Reading

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html
"I’m not a big fan of serving special retina images because it makes the web too heavy — especially over a mobile connection. Nonetheless people will do it." -- Peter-Paul Koch

*Update 2013-04-18* Update jQuery mobile link

Comment: thanks, i'm prone to accept the answer, but is Apple really the only manufacturer to produce hi-resolution displays? Doesn't -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio limits the browser usage to Safari and Chrome? What if i'm using Firefox on a Macbook Retina, for example?

Comment: @pistacchio, for your first question, beside Apple, Android also support hi-res but at 1.5. For second, the css solution could apply to all browsers, I added a line in code for browsers outside of webkit. Please check the updated version for detailed answers.

Comment: @pistacchio Windows Phone 8 supports high resolutions; the Lumia 920 _et al_ all have 720p displays with a pixel density actually higher than that of a Retina display.

Comment: For retina you say 18px background-size, but i think you mean 32px (same as before, just forced), just the image is actually 64px, right?

Comment: @Kevin, no, I still meant 18px. Imagine iPhone 3 and iPhone 5, which have similar screen size. Then in your site, a certain icon need to keep same size - 18px for these two devices. However, iPhone 5 support Retina, so you can use a high res icon 36x36 for it. You just force this 36x icon to show in actual size 18px. Though all is 18x, in iPhone 5 it will look much beautiful because it's high res now.

Comment: Your "orig icon" at the top is 36x36 though...  An easy solution is to use background-size: cover too though for css3 supporting browsers (which all retina ones are) unless you're spriting it

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;
```

this should make retina return true, which you could use an if function to serve the right images.

Source: http://briancray.com/posts/detect-retina-displays-with-javascript

-InfiniDaZa

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of network capabilities, responsive images and resource loading.

So far the javascript solutions are not quiet there as they generally require both resources (images) to be downloaded before the image swap.

Your best bet is background css media queries unless you go with a full solution like this:
http://adaptive-images.com
explained here: https://vimeo.com/38947881