# IBM Worklight - How to display retina-sized images in a Hybrid application

Tags: iphone, retina-display, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using double sized images for my IBM Worklight project for iPhone 4S environment, but when running the app in Xcode, I see the images not getting sized according to the iPhone 4S retina display in the Xcode Simulator, they are actually showing up the double sized images even bigger, with scroll.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed with this?

I am not using any @2x in my images filenames. This is my CSS:

```
#loginPage{
    width:225px;
    margin:120px 0 0 106px;
}

.textbox{
    background: url("../images/input_txt_bg.png") no-repeat;
    width:225px;
    height:68px;
    padding: 0 0 12px 20px;
    border:none;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #5A7890;
}

#loginBtn{
    background: url("../images/login_btn.png") no-repeat;
    width:225px;
    height:71px;
    border:none;
}
```

A similar question in IBM DeveloperWorks:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014898236

Comment: Can you add screen shots of the simulator, with the phenomena you're experiencing?

Comment: I would also make sure that in the Xcode Simulator program you have made sure pick the right simulator and iOS version that you're building for.

Comment: I am using the right hardware and simulator, everything has become huge and scrollable, its not showing exact compressed size. refer the link in the question you may get some idea, thanks for your help

Comment: Re-reading your question, something is not right... You're saying your images are double-sized only, and they appear like that, and that you're not using @2x in the filename. Maybe you mean they DON'T appear double-size while they should?

Comment: i am using double size images for iphone4s retina as you normally do, but when i run they dont get compressed instead i am getting scroll on my simulator.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what that means... I need an image. Why not just use @2x in the filename and let the OS handle the sizing?

Comment: i tried that but it still doesn't work, it doesn't fit in the screen size i need to scroll all my UI elements as they are big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this SO question will be beneficial for solving your problem: [Serving high res images to retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430828/serving-high-res-images-to-retina-display)