# Bing Maps pushpin for hi-resolution or retina displays

Tags: bing-maps

I'm working with a custom image for a pushpin using the Bing Maps v7 javascript libabry.  Everything works fine except the icons appear low-res / pixelated on an ipad or iphone with retina display.  I've tried changing the height width but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is really important with High definition screens is the actual resolution of the screen you're using.

To determine and adapt the url to use appropriate image with a higher resolution (by changing the path based on a variable), you can use:

```
var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;
```

If retina is set to true, then you would compose a specific path to the image to point to the correct one.

You should check this question and answers to be able to understand how things work regarding the image and also be able to deliver and adapt the result in the good resolution:

[Serving high res images to retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430828/serving-high-res-images-to-retina-display)

Comment: Yea this is not a bing maps issues... its simply a matter that CSS needed to set the height & width but the image needed to be 2x that size to display on retina images.